# select distinct rows based on 3 distinct columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
    id     userid     cc    cop    
    1       23        0.5   0.9
    2       23        0.5   0.9
    3       29        2.6   9.4
    4       75        4.8   8.9
    5       29        2.6   9.4
    6       45        6.7   9.0
```

I want all the roles such that cc and cop are distinct 1.e the result is supposed to be 
something like this

```
    id     userid     cc    cop    
    1       23        0.5   0.9
    3       29        2.6   9.4
    4       75        4.8   8.9
    6       45        6.7   9.0
```

i want of any rows that has cc,cop,userid the same only one should be selected
pseudocode: select * from table where userid,cc,cop are distinct from the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this

```
SELECT MIN(id), userid, cc, cop 
FROM table 
GROUP BY userid, cc, cop;
```

It will select the first id of each occurence.

Answer (score 2):

This will return the desired result whether how the records has been saved on the tables.

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, userid, cc, cop
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY userid, cc, cop
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01900/1)

OTHER Source(s)

- [MySQL GROUP BY clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a select statement that uses the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
GROUP BY userid
```

They are appearing as separate entries because each row has at least one distinct column (in this case, the id). You can avoid this by using the statement above OR by omitting the 'id' column from your SELECT statement, for example:

```
SELECT userid, cc, cop
FROM Table
```

If you select the data without the id column like above, then the data will automatically be grouped as there will be completely duplicate rows.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query with group by

```
select * from mytable group by userid , cc , cop
```

Comment: this will return the correct values **if** the `ID` is primary key and that it is saved on the table sequencially, otherwise it will not return the desired result (*not my downvote by the way*) for more clarification, see this demo. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11eb3/2

Comment: i didn't downvote you as well, I think that in case of duplicates the OP just wants one ID, no matter what, so I believe this answer is correct! I just want to add that when selecting nonaggregated columns in a group by query, mysql is free to chose any value for those columns, so there are no guarantees that it will always chose the first/minumum value, even if ID is primary key and is saved sequencially: this happens to be true in practice, but it's not documented and it's better not to relay on this.

Comment: thanks for your responses but the OP did not mentioned he needs MAX , MIN or RANDOM but one and this fulfils the requirement also people usually take id as primary key so i assumed the same thing